How to tune the unadjusted Langevin algorithm?
I want to start investigating the (unadjusted) simulation of the Langevin process $${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma{\rm d}W_t,$$ where $$b:=\frac{\sigma^2}2\nabla\ln p.$$ I don't want to simulate this process on $\mathbb R^d$, but on the torus $[0,1)^d$. I don't think that this is crucial for my question. However, in case it is, I'm assuming here that $$\int_{[0,\;1)^d}p=1$$ and $$p(k+x)=p(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb Z^d\text{ and }x\in[0,1)^d\tag1.$$ The process I'm now actually aiming to simulate is$^1$ $$Y_t:=X_t-\lfloor X_t\rfloor.$$
Now, I'm not sure if I should aim for exact sampling.$^2$ If not, I need to fall back to a discretization scheme like$^3$ $$X_{n+1}=X_n+\frac{\sigma^2}2h_{n+1}\nabla\ln p(X_n)+\sigma\sqrt{h_{n+1}}\xi_{n+1}\tag2,$$ where $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ is nonincreasing and $\xi_{n+1}\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)$. Consequentially, $$Y_n=X_n-\lfloor X_n\rfloor.\tag3$$

For a first test, I've considered the super simple example $$p(x):=\sum_{i=1}^d(1-\cos(2\pi x_i))\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1)^d.$$ I've chosen this $p$, since its periodic extension to $\mathbb R^d$ is smooth; which should help. However, it does vanish at the integer points $x\in\mathbb Z^d$. But this is a problem I also have in my application and hence cannot avoid.
Now, if we simply choose $\sigma=h_n=1$ AND apply a Metropolis-Hastings adjustment, I get the following histogram of 1M samples:

I stress that I don't want to use Metropolis-Hastings$^4$; I'm only considering it as the reference, since my goal is clearly to outperform it.
For the unadjusted simulation, I've chosen $$h_n=\frac c{(n_0+n)^\alpha}\tag5,$$ where $c>0$, $n_0\in\mathbb N$ and $\gamma\in(0,1)$. It's crucial that $h_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, since for a constant step size the invariant measure (if it exists) of the discretization might differ from the one of $X$.
I have kind of a hard time figuring out the right choices of the step size parameters. The best I came out with was $\sigma=1$, $c=1$, $n_0=10$ and $\gamma=1/3$, but they still give the worse looking histogram

after once again 1M samples. (For clarification, I'm weighting the $n$th sample with $h_{n+1}$ here; which should be the right way to do it).
So, any advice on this would be highly appreciated. I've also seen people using exponentially distributed time steppings (for example in Algorithm 1 here or the paper Efficient Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations Using Exponential Timestepping). Such an exponential time stepping would be convenient for me for another reason, but I wonder if it is really appropriate.

$^1$ The papers Langevin diffusions on the torus: estimation and applications and A Unifying and Canonical Description of Measure-Preserving Diffusions are related to that.
$^2$ In my application, I don't have analytical derivatives of $p$ available, but need to rely on automatic differentation instead. Also: Performance is critical and $d$ is large ($\ge16$). So, exact sampling might be too slow / infeasible.
$^3$ Yes, I'm abusing notation in the subscripts, but I think it's clear that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are now the discretizations of the continuous-time processes.
$^4$ It introduces rejections and destroys any possible nonreversibility I might add in the future; the reason why I started to consider direct simulation of the Langevin process now.
